# Having trouble plotting my data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty desperated. I ran into a problem when trying to plot my data. 
The first circle plot works perfect, but I'm having problems with the second one `plt.plot(x, y)`. When trying to plot it with the code below, I don't get any error messages, but the computation never goes into the elif loop - which it should considering the sill value is below 20000 and the x values go up to 95000. It keeps calculating the y-values with the if loop. I tried everything I could to fix it, but either I create new error messages, or I keep having the same problem.

Anyone got an idea how to fix the code or where the problem is located? Would really appreciate an answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
b = 1.748
sill = 19506.208
x = np.linspace(0,95000,1000)
if (x < b).any():
    y = np.multiply(sill,( np.multiply(1.5,(x/b)) - 
    (np.multiply(0.5,((x/b)**3.0)))))
elif (x > b).any():
    y = sill
plt.plot(Abstandsmatrix_Tage, Varianzmatrix_Tage, 'ro')
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to iterate over `x` when assigning your `y` values. or do it in a list comprehension:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
b = 1.748
sill = 19506.208
x = np.linspace(0,95000,1000)

y = [np.multiply(sill,( np.multiply(1.5,(i/b)) - (np.multiply(0.5,((i/b)**3.0))))) if i < b else sill for i in x]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, with your example, only the first value of `x` is less than `b`, and that is 0, so you end up with:

```
y = [0.0, 19506.208, 19506.208, 19506.208, ... ]
```

So, maybe you mean `if x < sill`, instead of `if x < b`? If so:

```
y = [np.multiply(sill,( np.multiply(1.5,(i/b)) - (np.multiply(0.5,((i/b)**3.0))))) if i < sill else sill for i in x]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot!!!
I'm by far not so experienced than you with python. What I meant was the first thing you posted, it works perfect when iterating over 'x as i'. But to be honest, I'd have never come up with that idea myself. At least at my experience level right now. I'm glad that there are guys like you in this forum. Thanks!!!